# Dá para usar Firebird acessando do Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, firebird

Desenvolvi uma aplicação C# Windows Forms com Visual Studio 2013 e com banco de dados Firebird, mas gostaria de fazer um pequeno aplicativo para facilitar o acesso ao sistema. Porém neste aplicativo seria necessário acessar o mesmo banco de dados da aplicação para inserir e consultar alguns registros.

É possível conectar este aplicativo ao banco Firebird? E essa conexão segue o mesmo esquema do Windows Forms? Como faço isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta é um pouco ampla mas vou responder o que dá.

Possível até é, se não houver bloqueios de rede. Mesmo que não tenha, não é ideal dar acesso ao banco de dados para aplicações que você não tem controle como estão rodando. Muitos dirão que é melhor ter um intermediário em qualquer situação. Ou seja, ter uma solução usando arquitetura cliente-servidor real e não ter o banco de dados funcionando como servidor da aplicação.

A solução para estes casos é ter um servidor de aplicação que acessa o banco de dados e fornece os dados requisitados pelo aplicativo. Este servidor pode ser baseado em web, assim garante compatibilidade praticamente com qualquer rede, afinal porta 80 costuma ser sempre aberta.

Se optar por usar tecnologia web (mesmo que não tenha um site acessando), precisará aprender programar com [ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou algo que faça a mesma função. A nova versão do [ASP.NET integrou o MVC com o WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (só use esta versão para projetos novos, a [anterior morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101)).

Comment: Então eu devo desenvolver tipo um site onde ficariam armazenados os dados e assim acessá-los no aplicativo Windows Phone e na aplicação Windows Forms através dessa WebAPI? Porém eu ainda consigo usar firebird ou eu deveria mudar para sql?

Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Não é que seja um *site*, é algo parecido. Ele usa a mesma tecnologia mas não vai montar páginas HTML para navegador (bom, até pode fazer isto também, se desejar). Mas tem outras tecnologias, até um pouco mais eficientes. Claro que elas tem suas desvantagens próprias. Aí se vai mudar sua aplicação WinForms para acessar estas aplicação, é uma decisão sua. Eu não faria inicialmente. Deixa como está e um dia você verá se vale a pena. Firebird é SQL. Pode continuar usando ele. Estas foram ideias gerais.

Comment: Entendi., mas acho que eu perguntei errado, pois eu terei que hospedar esta aplicação web em algum servidor muito provavelmente. Portanto para isso é possível continuar usando Firebird ou devo mudar para Sql Server?

Comment: Não necessariamente, mas é óbvio que o aplicativo terá que ter acesso à aplicação em algum lugar. Seria o mesmo se fosse fazer o acesso direto ao banco de dados. Pode continuar usando o FIrebird, isto não muda nada.

Comment: Ok então, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se tiver dúvidas mais específicas, vai perguntando.

Comment: Cara estou com novas dúvidas. Dentro do meu projeto (solution) existem algumas partes, então eu tenho a parte desktop que tem as classes e repositórios, e tenho a parte da web api que eu fiz baseado nesse site (http://csharpbrasil.com.br/criando-e-consumindo-web-api-parte-1/). Daí eu quero te perguntar se o jeito que eu fiz a api está correto, porque adicionou um monte de referências? E agora eu preciso desenvolver o app do Windows Phone, como eu consumo os dados dessa api no app, pois o que eu vi até agora é necessário usar as classes, mas as minha classes estão na outra parte do projeto?